# How does ethereum plan to fix crypto kitties issue?

Tags: ether

Transactions are pretty much halted on ethereum due to cryptokittes.

Is there any intermediate solutions?

Recently I managed to send ethereum with only 9 gas price.

Why did the congestion go away? What happened?

Comment: *"Transactions are pretty much halted on ethereum due to cryptokittes."* I've done numerous transactions with 40gwei that have been completed in about 20 seconds. I've not experienced any slowdown due to cryptokitties in recent days. What gas price are you using?

Comment: Congestion is a relative term. There is a gas price market. When there is more traffic in the network you should expect to pay a higher price to have your transaction handled in the same amount of time.

Comment: Much like pokemon go, it was in the news and lots of people wanted to know about the novelty, now the interest has diminished and the network is back at the usual level (also the increase in block gas limit to 8M has helped some).

Comment: 9 gwei is enough now.

Answer (score 1):

Metamask team had a nice overview about this problem:

> Sorry for any delays in getting back to your pending support tickets, in the last week, since CryptoKitties launched, we’ve gained over 80 thousand new users!

https://medium.com/metamask/metamask-cryptokitty-performance-update-83d851af0147